# Why is the pattern validation not working here?

Tags: javascript, angular, regex, validation

I`m receiving this error: "requiredPattern": "^/(https://)([[:alnum:]]).+$/ig$", "actualValue" "https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.K2YpOtFQ-JED8eDsHg7pdwHaEK?w=320&h=180&c=7&r=0&o=5&dpr=1.3&pid=1.7"

This should be matched by testing on regex101 : [image: regex 101]

I`m using reactive forms.

I`ve tried this way of giving the pattern :

```
    imageUrl: [``, [ Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^/(https:\/\/)([[:alnum:]]).+$/ig')]],
```

Also making a variable urlPattern :

```
 urlPattern = /(https:\/\/)([[:alnum:]]).+/ig
```

And calling it like this :

```
    imageUrl: [``, [ Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.urlPattern)]],
```

My form is validation in the html is like this :

```
<div *ngIf="createProductForm.get('imageUrl')?.errors?.['pattern']">
                    Image URL is invalid!
</div>
```

It shows up, but not accepting the pattern while it should be?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FWIW, I have occasionally seen regexes defined as strings on pattern validators not work the same as a regex class instance.

Comment: Perhaps like this `Validators.pattern(/^https:\/\/[a-zA-Z\d]\S+$/ig)`

Comment: @Thefourthbird Yes, it did work like this. Why was mine not accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript does not support POSIX bracket expressions like `[[:alnum:]]`

Instead you could write like `[a-z\d]` with the case insensitive flag `/i` and then match 1 or more non whitspace characters using `\S+`

Then use `/^` instead of  `^/` and for a match only you can omit the capture groups.

```
Validators.pattern(/^https?:\/\/[a-z\d]\S+$/i)
```